# How to pass parameters to scrapy crawler from scrapyd?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I can run a spider in scrapy with a simple command

`scrapy crawl custom_spider -a input_val=5 -a input_val2=6`

where `input_val` and `input_val2` are the values i'm passing to the spider

and the above method works fine..

However while scheduling a spider with scrapyd

running

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=crawler -d input_val=5 -d input_val2=6 -d spider=custom_spider
```

Throws an error

```
spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
    exceptions.TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_job'
```

How do i get this to work?

**Edit**
This: is inside my initializer:

```
def __init__(self,input_val=None, input_val2=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.input_val = input_val
        self.input_val2 = input_val2
        super(CustomSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to support arbitrary keyword arguments in your spider and call `__init__` with `super()` [like shown in the docs for spider arguments](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments):

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def __init__(self, category=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # <- important
        self.category = category
```

Scrapyd supplies the job ID as a `_job` argument passed to the spider (see [code here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/blob/master/scrapyd/webservice.py#L38)).

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the question with the constructor, the error is still there.... any idea what is wrong?

Comment: @wolfgang hm, what version of scrapy and scrapyd are you using? could you provide a small self-contained sample project that reproduces the problem when deployed to scrapyd?

Comment: @wolfgang I was not able to reproduce the problem with the code you provided.

Comment: yes, will get that self-contained code, checked and spider works with your code suggestions, but for some cases it does'nt (probably some misconfig on my end) will let you know, thanks